# Changing to a horizontal stack display with GNU dc?

Tags: forth, dc

GNU DC displays the stack vertically, (`f` displays the stack)

```
1 2 3 4
f  # to display the stack
4
3
2
1
```

Is there a way to change this to be more like FORTH? While GNU FORTH displays the stack horizontally, (`.s` displays the stack)

```
1 2 3 4  ok
.s <4> 1 2 3 4  ok
```

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `dc` works the way it does. You can find the source and change it I suppose. But why is it important or overall problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can always redefine `f` if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom function in ~/.dcrc which is read each time dc start.

cat ~/.dcrc

```
[
# if the stack is empty
[ 2 + [stack empty] p 0 :- Q ]s-
z d 0 =- 0 :-
# keep the stack in indexed array -
[ z :- z 0 <- ]s-
l-x
# restore the stack
[ 0 ;- 1 + d ;- ;- r d ;- 1 + r :- 0 ;- d 1 + ;- r !<- ]s-
1 0 ;- 1 + :-
l-x
# displays the stack horizontally
[ 0 ;- d 1 + d ;- ;- n [ ] n d d ;- 1 + r :- ;- !>- ]s-
1 0 ;- 1 + :- l-x [ ok] p 0 :-
]s-
```

You call it this way :

```
echo '7 16 8 9' | dc -f - -e 'l-x f'
```

and you get :

```
7 16 8 9  ok
9
8
16
7
```

You cannot use register -